# How to deploy Springboot app in Linux along with Maven dependencies

Tags: java, linux, maven, spring-boot

I have created a Spring Boot java application (REST Services) which uses Tomcat internally as web server on Windows machine using Eclipse as IDE. It uses JDK 1.8 & Maven as build system. Here I create jar file (Run as Maven Install ) and then invoke that jar file from command prompt in my windows machine. I test these REST services using POSTMAN on my Windows machine.

Now I have to get it working on an Linux machine which does not have UI. Can you please help me how to achieve same on Linux machine and how to get those dependencies on Linux machine.

Comment: copy your jar file to linux machine and you are good to go. but, you must have java and maven installed in Linux machine.

Comment: Do you use spring-boot-maven-plugin and package as a jar file? If so you only need to run your app the jar file and a JRE ...

Comment: Simply to start a spring boot app: `java -jar spring-boot-app.jar`..

Answer (score 0):

first, make sure your Linux server have Java installed. Best match your local java version.

second, make use of maven plugin to generate a shell script which can kick off this project.

Below is an example

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
    <!-- bind to package phase -->
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-appassembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>assemble</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <!-- set alternative assemble directory -->
        <assembleDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}
        </assembleDirectory>
        <environmentSetupFileName>envSetup.sh</environmentSetupFileName>
        <includeConfigurationDirectoryInClasspath>true</includeConfigurationDirectoryInClasspath>
        <repositoryLayout>flat</repositoryLayout>
        <repositoryName>lib</repositoryName>
        <platforms>
            <!-- <platform>windows</platform> -->
            <platform>unix</platform>
        </platforms>
        <!-- Extra JVM arguments that will be included in the bin scripts -->
        <extraJvmArguments>-Dlog4j.configuration=file:$BASEDIR/etc/log4j.properties
            -Dapplication.properties=file:$BASEDIR/etc/XXX.properties
            -Xms2048m
            -Xmx12288m -server -showversion -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
            -DXXX.log.dir=XXX
            -DXXX.app.id=XXX
        </extraJvmArguments>
        <programs>
            <program>
                <mainClass>com.xxx.App</mainClass>
                <name>xxx.sh</name>
            </program></programs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```